# Cups and Plates of the same Colors

Tags: combinatorics

I need help to solve a problem about  finding the probability of a event.

I have 3 pairs of cup and plate of 3 diferent colors(1 red cup - 1 red plate, 1 blue cup - 1 blue plate, 1 white cup - 1 white plate). What is the probability to have no pairs of cups and plates of the same colors?

Comment: so at each try, 3 pairs are picked, each containing one cup and one plate ? And each object can be either red, blue or white ? that'd do 8 cases out of 27 where none of the pairs have the two objects of the same color.

Answer (score 0):

Let the cups be represented by smaller letters and plates with capital letters.
For each plate, there are three possible cups. For each combination of plate and cup, there are two combinations for the other two plates and cups. Hence there are 6 combinations.
The possible selections are:
$$Rr, Ww, Bb$$
$$Rr, Wb, Bw$$
$$Rb, Ww, Br$$
$$Rb, Wr, Bw$$
$$Rw, Wr, Bb$$
$$Rw, Wb, Br$$

In total there are 6 possibilities out of which there are only two (fourth and sixth cases) where the color of each cup is different from its plate. Hence the probability is $\frac {2}{6}$, i.e. $\frac {1}{3}$.